# Is there a way (a package?) to "redirect" pop-up menus to the minibuffer, ido, or completion buffer; either generic or flyspell-specific

Tags: package, ido, menus

Sometimes I must use Emacs (in X mode) over a network connection (for example, working on a cloud VM). I am pretty comfortable with the interface responsiveness inside a frame, although X is notoriously sensitive to network delays. But when it comes to any type of creating a new X window, be it a menu, a tooltip or a new frame, I'm looking at a few seconds wait. Tolerably painful if I want a new frame--this is not something I do often--but entirely unusable for a menu.

Unfortunately, flyspell, that I often use, is hard-coded to invoke `x-popup-menu`¹. Fixing a typo manually is certainly faster than popping up the menu, but there is not a function in it to add the word to dictionary, and this is where the menu gets me.

But nothing in principle prevents one from fbinding their own override version of `x-popup-menu` to intercept calls to it. So my question is, essentially, two-part:

1. Is there a more or less generic way (a package, presumably) that converts pop-up menus into (ideally) ido prompts, or other in-frame interface, e. g., the usual completion buffer? This would be a win for me!
2. If such a thing does not exist, is there a flyspell-specific modification: a package that hooks into flyspell, or a fork that does not use menus, or just anything but the popups?

---

I am aware of certain alternatives. For example, I use tramp mode over SSH when feasible and edit remote files in a local, responsive Emacs. But it often happens that all I have on me is a Windows laptop, so a remote X client is the only practical option.

---

¹ Tangentially, and curiously, for the (late) XEmacs flyspell has a separate code path that invokes the more general, window-system-agnostic `popup-menu` function, which exists, and is *supposedly* compatible, in GNU Emacs. Even though the XEmacs project has been thoroughly dead for a decade, being one of its major developers, I can't stop wondering what was the reason for this...

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I've been using flyspell for 5+ years and I had completely forgotten that there is even a pop-up available.  If flyspell-mode is active, the default is just to wavy-underline a misspelled word without using popups.  When I am finished with the document, I run `ispell-buffer` and am then presented with a buffer of various options to choose from.  You may be interested in doing something similar and bypass the pop-up feature entirely.  I would have to trace the functions to figure out how you are getting the popup to even happen, but popups are not mandatory.

Comment: @lawlist, thank you. `ispell-buffer` is not what I am looking for, as it prompts for everything it considers mispellings, including even parts of identifiers. 99% of what I edit is code. Ideally, I want to hit a chord and select a replacement word or an option to save to dictionary the word at the point, and this single word only. I am not aware of any ispell function that allows this--do you know of one? I think I must dig deeper into it.

Comment: You might want to check out my [frog-menu](https://github.com/clemera/frog-menu) package.

Comment: @clemera, although your package is not something I can use directly (remember, _anything_ that wants to pop up is a disaster over a higher-latency X link, posframe won't cut it), the package you are giving in an example is probably just what I need (https://gitlab.com/d12frosted/flyspell-correct/blob/master/flyspell-correct-ido.el). So thanks for the pointer, I'll give that one a try!

Comment: @kkm You can use `frog-menu-type` set to `avy-side-window` to avoid posframe.

Comment: @clemera, good to know, thanks. Ido has been my interface workhorse for years, but I'll explore your option one day!

Comment: @kkm Ido is great for completion but this is about picking candidates from a list which you can't really filter efficently via completion, judge yourself ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you're asking, but this might be a partial answer, although I don't think it applies to `(x-)popup-menu`.

If some code explicitly invokes `(x-)popup-menu` then it has chosen to use a popup menu. As far as I know, you have no choice in that case; it's hard-coded.

You could of course copy the source code, change it to use keyboard input, and use your own, modified commands instead of those provided by the library. You could also request that the library maintainer offer users a choice in this.

---

Here's what I was going to mention, which is not about popup menus:

If you customize option `use-dialog-box` to non-`nil` then mouse-initiated commands use dialog boxes instead of the keyboard to query you.

If you also customize `use-file-dialog` to non-`nil` then the same happens for file selection: a file-selection dialog box is used. In this case the dialog box is used even if the command is initiated from the keyboard.

On MS Windows, if you customize option `w32-use-w32-font-dialog` to non-`nil` then font selection uses the standard Windows font-selection dialog.

Comment: “If[…] code[…] invokes `(x-)popup-menu` then it has chosen to use a popup menu”--this is true, but then it's up to the environment how to interpret the UI presentation of a popup menu. “you have no choice in that case”--see `defadvice`, a high-level alternative to directly fbinding built-in functions. An example package is ido-yes-or-no that defadvice's the `yes-or-no-p` to change its UI behavior. Thanks for other pointers; it happened so that I already have these (and more) customized. But I shall indeed upvote your answer, as it is generally useful--to others... :(

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that I asked this question before, got frustrated by the slow link again, started googling, and this was the first page that came up in search. Not a good sign... So I did it. Hope someone would use it one day.

This relies on string keys in `plist` be `eq` to strings in `choices`: this is how `plist-get` works; the strings must not be copied. Not that I can think of a scenario where that would make sense; a reminder just in case.

If someone would want to make that into a package, please do. This can be generalized by attaching a concrete function (like this one which parses the menu and returns something that `flyspell-correct-word-before-point` expects to get from its `x-popup-menu` call) as a property of a command symbol (`'flyspell-correct-word-before-point` in this case).

```el
(require 'ido)

;; This can be generalized by attaching a property to command symbol.
(defun x-popup-menu--advice-around (f &rest args)
  (if (or (not (eq 'flyspell-correct-word-before-point this-command))
          (ignore-errors (mouse-event-p (car args))))
      (apply f args) ; Not our guy, or called via a mouse event, run normally.

    ;; Called via keyboard, do ido-completing-read.
    (let* ((mdesc (cadadr args))
           (prompt (concat (car mdesc) ": ")) ; Menu title.
           (mbody (cdr mdesc)) ; Menu body: (("foo" "foo") ... "" ... ) ; Menu body.
           (plist (mapcan (lambda (p) (and p (listp p)
                                           (list (car p) (cdr p))))
                          mbody)) ; (display_name (value) ... )
           (choices (mapcan (lambda (p) (and p (listp p)
                                             (list (car p))))
                            mbody))) ; (display_name ...)
      ;; Every value in the plist is a 1-element list.
      (plist-get plist
                 (ido-completing-read prompt choices nil t)))))

(add-hook 'flyspell-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (if (not flyspell-mode)
                (advice-remove 'x-popup-menu #'x-popup-menu--advice-around)
              (advice-add 'x-popup-menu :around #'x-popup-menu--advice-around)
              (define-key flyspell-mode-map [(control ?\.)]
                #'flyspell-correct-word-before-point))))
```